# Renpy, making the user choose between a male or female MC and also adding a custom name

Tags: renpy

The thing I'm struggling on at the moment as probably as basic as this is, is to create a code that lets the player choose whether they want to play as a male or female MC and also having it that they can either input their own name if they want then otherwise default it to what the characters names would be

I tried creating and else if and tried to follow youtube videos but it didn't work the way it was supposed too